# How to use Cox ISP and maintain secure account information?

Tags: account-security, isp

Cox ISP has been changing my account information like my address, phone number and name to the wrong addresses, names and phone numbers.

I ask them to make the corrections and they don't.  Instead they again change to the wrong details again.

Sometimes they hang up on me or transfer my call or chat repeatedly to avoid helping me.

Obviously there are customer service reps that have access to my account information and are messing it all up.

This is a very undesirable information security vulnerability existing in Cox.  **My bill is not even sent to the right address!**

How to use Cox ISP and maintain secure account information?

Is the answer to not talk to their customer support representatives who always seem to gain access to my account information and mess it up?  Or is a better answer to not use Cox at all?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79788/discussion-on-question-by-eeshwar-das-how-to-use-cox-isp-and-maintain-secure-acc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my answer on your previous post, if you don't like your ISP there really isn't a whole lot you can do about it.

You either deal with them or you change ISP, of course, you can call them and ask them questions about how they handle your information but chances are they are not at all obligated to answer them.

Honestly, I don't think anybody here will be able to help you. As Forest mentioned in the comments of the last post, ISPs are not obligated to help you it's mostly an additional service they provide. If the network goes down they will fix it but other than that they are not obligated to help.

Comment: J   -  Yes thank you.  I agree with part of your answer.  It is only that the other post became deleted so I could not give you any response.  Thank you for following up again.  Maybe I was using the wrong language in the previous post so the moderators deleted it.  It appears that again I may need to be more clear.  We can forget about the side-effects of the bad customer support.  To me it seems like if I pay the ISP for internet services, they should be required to have my name, address and phone number correct in their account information.

Comment: Your last post was deleted because as Schroeder has stated (and I have in my answer) we cannot help you, whilst you're worried about your data we're not lawyers and we don't work for the ISP thus we cannot help you beyond "Change your ISP"

Comment: J  -  Please don't underestimate your responses.  It is very helpful to hear that a solution is to change to a more respectable ISP.  Thank you.